# How do I stack only some columns in a data frame?

Tags: r, reshape

I have some data in a data frame in the following form:

```
A  B  C  V1  V2  V3
1  1  1  x   y   z
1  1  2  a   b   c
...
```

Where A,B,C are factors, and the combination A,B,C is unique for each row.

I need to convert some of the columns into factors, to achieve a form like:

```
A  B  C  V  val
1  1  1  V1 x
1  1  1  V2 y
1  1  1  V3 z
1  1  2  V1 a
1  1  2  V2 b
1  1  2  V2 c
...
```

This seems to relate to both [stack](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/stack.html) and the inverse of [xtabs](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/xtabs.html), but I don't see how to specify that only certain columns should be "stacked".

Comment: See `reshape` and the reshape package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `reshape2` package

```
dat <- read.table(text = 'A  B  C  V1  V2  V3
1  1  1  x   y   z
1  1  2  a   b   c',header= T)
library(reshape2)
melt(dat,id.vars = c('A','B','C'))
 A B C variable value
1 1 1 1       V1     x
2 1 1 2       V1     a
3 1 1 1       V2     y
4 1 1 2       V2     b
5 1 1 1       V3     z
6 1 1 2       V3     c
```

Answer (score 5):

And before @AnandaMahto gets here and offers his base `reshape` solution, here's my attempt:

```
dat <- read.table(text = 'A  B  C  V1  V2  V3
1  1  1  x   y   z
1  1  2  a   b   c',header= T)

expandvars <- c("V1","V2","V3")

datreshape <- reshape(dat,
                   idvar=c("A","B","C"),
                   varying=list(expandvars),
                   v.names=c("val"),
                   times=expandvars,
                   direction="long")

> datreshape
         A B C time val
1.1.1.V1 1 1 1   V1   x
1.1.2.V1 1 1 2   V1   a
1.1.1.V2 1 1 1   V2   y
1.1.2.V2 1 1 2   V2   b
1.1.1.V3 1 1 1   V3   z
1.1.2.V3 1 1 2   V3   c
```

Comment: @agstudy, it's nice to have some other shapeshifters in my company. +1 to both of you.

Comment: @agstudy and Thela (sorry, you're stuck with that name now), I can't resist [adding an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14639977/1270695) to a reshape question. (I should seek help....)

Comment: +1 to all, thanks! I didn't realize there was a community of R ninjas on SO.

Answer (score 3):

### `stack`

You are right that `stack` is a possibility, but you perhaps missed a key line in the documentation for `stack`:

> Note that stack applies to vectors (as determined by is.vector): non-vector columns (e.g., factors) will be ignored (with a warning as from R 2.15.0).

So, how do we proceed?

Here's your data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = 'A  B  C  V1  V2  V3
    1  1  1  x   y   z
    1  1  2  a   b   c',header= T)
```

Here, we convert the factors to `as.character`:

```
dat[sapply(dat, is.factor)] = lapply(dat[sapply(dat, is.factor)], as.character)
```

Here's how we specify which columns to `stack`:

```
stack(dat[4:6])
#   values ind
# 1      x  V1
# 2      a  V1
# 3      y  V2
# 4      b  V2
# 5      z  V3
# 6      c  V3
```

But, we still need to "expand" your rows for columns 1-3. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2894825/1270695) for how to do that.

With this information, we can use `cbind` to get the desired result.

```
cbind(dat[rep(row.names(dat), 3), 1:3], stack(dat[4:6]))
#     A B C values ind
# 1   1 1 1      x  V1
# 2   1 1 2      a  V1
# 1.1 1 1 1      y  V2
# 2.1 1 1 2      b  V2
# 1.2 1 1 1      z  V3
# 2.2 1 1 2      c  V3
```

### `xtabs`

You are also right that `xtabs` seems like it could be a likely possibility, but `xtabs` actually expects the *opposite* of what you've provided. That is to say, when you specify a formula, it expects the items on the left hand side to be numbers, and the items on the right hand side to be factors. Thus, is your data were swapped, you *could* certainly use `xtabs`.

Here's a demonstration (which only works because you are using a simple example where we can easily `match` "letters" to "numbers").

```
dat2 <- dat # Make a copy of "dat"
# Swap out dat 4-6 with numbers
dat2[4:6] <- lapply(dat2[4:6], function(x) match(x, letters))
# Swap out dat 1-3 with letters
dat2[1:3] <- lapply(dat2[1:3], function(x) letters[x])
# Our new "dat"
dat2
#   A B C V1 V2 V3
# 1 a a a 24 25 26
# 2 a a b  1  2  3
data.frame(xtabs(cbind(V1, V2, V3) ~ A + B + C, dat2))
#   A B C Var4 Freq
# 1 a a a   V1   24
# 2 a a b   V1    1
# 3 a a a   V2   25
# 4 a a b   V2    2
# 5 a a a   V3   26
# 6 a a b   V3    3
```

---

In other words, your choice of tools could potentially be right, but your data needs to also be in the form that the tools expect.

But, I'm not sure why you'd want to do all the work I've shown when better solutions exist with `reshape` and friends ;)

---

#### Very late update...

You can also look at `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(dat, var.stubs = "V", sep = "NoSep")
#    A B C .time_1 V
# 1: 1 1 1      V1 x
# 2: 1 1 1      V2 y
# 3: 1 1 1      V3 z
# 4: 1 1 2      V1 a
# 5: 1 1 2      V2 b
# 6: 1 1 2      V3 c
```

Or `gather` from "tidyr":

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
# gather(dat, var, val, V1:V3)
dat %>% gather(var, val, V1:V3) 
#   A B C var val
# 1 1 1 1  V1   x
# 2 1 1 2  V1   a
# 3 1 1 1  V2   y
# 4 1 1 2  V2   b
# 5 1 1 1  V3   z
# 6 1 1 2  V3   c
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I'm only just starting to understand the R data model, this is the sort of reply that provides very useful insight.

Comment: @saffsd, no problem. SO is a good place to learn about these things. Do be sure to read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) though, and try to share your question in a reproducible format.

Comment: Following up from an old post, the base version can be made simpler like `cbind(dat[1:3],stack(lapply(dat[4:6],as.character)))` - no need to explicitly repeat the rows.