# How do I reshape this data frame with R?

Tags: r, reshape

I'm new to R and needed some help with reshaping a data frame that is similar to the one below:

| company_name | year | profit_usd | profit_eur | profit_gbp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2017 | 1237 | 1006 | 871 |
| B | 2017 | 1337 | 1096 | 949 |
| A | 2018 | 1143 | 937 | 811 |
| B | 2018 | 1288 | 1056 | 914 |

I want to reshape this table such that I have only one column which shows profit and another column which shows the currency name. Something like this:

| company_name | year | currency | profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2017 | usd | 1237 |
| A | 2017 | eur | 1006 |
| A | 2017 | gbp | 871 |
| B | 2017 | usd | 1337 |
| B | 2017 | eur | 1096 |
| B | 2017 | gbp | 949 |
| A | 2018 | usd | 1143 |
| A | 2018 | eur | 937 |
| A | 2018 | gbp | 811 |
| B | 2018 | usd | 1288 |
| B | 2018 | eur | 1056 |
| B | 2018 | gbp | 914 |

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd provided your data not ina table, e.g. by using `dput(YOURDATA)` or, if the data is too large `dput(head(YOURDATA))`. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @deschen Thank you for the tip - I'll keep that in mind for future questions

Comment: @zx8754: I vote for reopening this question. Not every question on a reshape topic can be answered by this one post you linked. I.e. in this particular case, we can make good use of the `names_sep` parameter in `pivot_longer`, which isn't a viable option in the post you linked.

Comment: I agree that this isn't covered by the post it's flagged for, but it's definitely a question that's been posted before. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25925556/5325862) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23945350/5325862) seem like better targets. @zx8754 would you want to add either of those?

Comment: @deschen feel free to vote to re-open if disagree.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is stored in an object `df`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols      = starts_with("profit"),
               names_sep = "_",
               names_to  = c("delete", "currency"),
               values_to = "profit") %>%
  select(-delete)
```

Comment: Feel free to mark it (or any other answer you deem helpful) as your accepted answer, so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the answer of deschen.

```
library(tidyr)

#long format
df <- pivot_longer(df, cols = c("profit_usd", "profit_eur", "profit_gbp"), names_to = "currency", values_to = "profit")

#removes profit_ from your currency column
df$currency <- gsub("profit_", "", df$currency)
```

I have a personal preference not to use pipe functions. Especially when starting out, the use of pipe functions can create long lines of code which are harder to debug in comparison with multiple lines. Advantage of pipe functions is shorter code ofcourse.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the tip - I will keep that in mind moving forward!