# Reshape multiple columns R. Columns inverted

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, melt

Following this question I got a very strange behaviour with `base` reshape:
[Reshaping wide to long with multiple values columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945350/reshaping-wide-to-long-with-multiple-values-columns)

Here, it works:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                 blabla=c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"),
                 age.t0=c(7,8,9,10),
                 height.t0=c(120.2, 130.2, 112.1, 109.5),
                 weight.t0=c(31,32,33,34),
                 age.t1=c(8,9,10,11),
                 height.t1=c(125.7, 132.4, 118.2, 114.6),
                 weight.t1=c(331,332,333,334))

> df
  id blabla age.t0 height.t0 weight.t0 age.t1 height.t1 weight.t1
1  a    aaa      7     120.2        31      8     125.7       331
2  b    bbb      8     130.2        32      9     132.4       332
3  c    ccc      9     112.1        33     10     118.2       333
4  d    ddd     10     109.5        34     11     114.6       334

df.l <- reshape(df, direction='long', 
                varying=c("age.t0", "height.t0", "weight.t0", "age.t1", "height.t1", "weight.t1"), 
                timevar='var',
                times=c('t0', 't1'),
                v.names=c('age', 'height', "weight"),
                idvar='id')

> df.l
     id blabla var age height weight
a.t0  a    aaa  t0   7  120.2     31
b.t0  b    bbb  t0   8  130.2     32
c.t0  c    ccc  t0   9  112.1     33
d.t0  d    ddd  t0  10  109.5     34
a.t1  a    aaa  t1   8  125.7    331
b.t1  b    bbb  t1   9  132.4    332
c.t1  c    ccc  t1  10  118.2    333
d.t1  d    ddd  t1  11  114.6    334
```

But if I change the `v.names` value `weight` to `growth` in `reshape`, the columns are inverted...

```
df.l <- reshape(df, direction='long', 
    varying=c("age.t0", "height.t0", "weight.t0", "age.t1", "height.t1", "weight.t1"), 
    timevar='var',
    times=c('t0', 't1'),
    v.names=c('age', 'height', "growth"), ## Change is here. weight --> growth
    idvar='id')

> df.l
     id blabla var age height growth
a.t0  a    aaa  t0   7     31  120.2
b.t0  b    bbb  t0   8     32  130.2
c.t0  c    ccc  t0   9     33  112.1
d.t0  d    ddd  t0  10     34  109.5
a.t1  a    aaa  t1   8    331  125.7
b.t1  b    bbb  t1   9    332  132.4
c.t1  c    ccc  t1  10    333  118.2
d.t1  d    ddd  t1  11    334  114.6
```

The same happens if the variables names are changed directly in `df`.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                 blabla=c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"),
                 age.t0=c(7,8,9,10),
                 height.t0=c(120.2, 130.2, 112.1, 109.5),
                 growth.t0=c(31,32,33,34), ## weight --> growth
                 age.t1=c(8,9,10,11),
                 height.t1=c(125.7, 132.4, 118.2, 114.6),
                 growth.t1=c(331,332,333,334)) ## weight --> growth

> df
  id blabla age.t0 height.t0 growth.t0 age.t1 height.t1 growth.t1
1  a    aaa      7     120.2        31      8     125.7       331
2  b    bbb      8     130.2        32      9     132.4       332
3  c    ccc      9     112.1        33     10     118.2       333
4  d    ddd     10     109.5        34     11     114.6       334

df.l <- reshape(df, direction='long', 
                varying=c("age.t0", "height.t0", "growth.t0", 
                          "age.t1", "height.t1", "growth.t1"), ## weight --> growth
                timevar='var',
                times=c('t0', 't1'),
                v.names=c('age', 'height', "growth"),
                idvar='id')

> df.l
     id blabla var age height growth
a.t0  a    aaa  t0   7     31  120.2
b.t0  b    bbb  t0   8     32  130.2
c.t0  c    ccc  t0   9     33  112.1
d.t0  d    ddd  t0  10     34  109.5
a.t1  a    aaa  t1   8    331  125.7
b.t1  b    bbb  t1   9    332  132.4
c.t1  c    ccc  t1  10    333  118.2
d.t1  d    ddd  t1  11    334  114.6
```

So, this is super strange. Also, if you replace `growth` in `v.names` with, e.g. `a` or `b`, columns are inverted, but not with e.g. `i` or `q`.

Comment: It seems to be alphabetizing.