# R data.frame flow data pre-processing for aggregated time statistics

Tags: r, awk, dataframe, aggregate

What is the most efficient way of processing a flow data.frame like

```
> df <- data.frame(amount=c(4,3,1,1,4,5,9,13,1,1), size=c(164,124,131,315,1128,331,1135,13589,164,68), tot=1, first=c(1,1,3,3,2,2,2,2,4,4), secs=c(2,2,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0))
> df
  amount  size   tot first secs
1      4   164     1     1    2
2      3   124     1     1    2
3      1   131     1     3    0
4      1   315     1     3    0
5      4  1128     1     2    1
6      5   331     1     2    1
7      9  1135     1     2    1
8     13 13589     1     2    1
9      1   164     1     4    0
10     1    68     1     4    0
```

to an per-time aggregated totals

```
> df2
  time tot amount  size
1    1   2    3.5   144
2    2   6   34.5 16327
3    3   8   36.5 16773
4    4   2    2.0   232
```

.. using R, when the actual data-set can be more than 100 000 000 rows or even tens of gigabytes?

Column `first` denotes the start of a flow with duration `secs`, with metrics `amount`, `size`, and `tot`. In aggregated totals the `size` and `amount` are evenly divided to the time range in double-precision, whereas `tot` is summed to every time-slot as an integer. Duration `secs` denotes how many time-slots the flows last in addition to value `first`: If `secs` is 1 and `first` is 5, the flow lasts time-slots 5 and 6. My current implementation uses ugly and dead-slow for-loops, which is not an option:

```
df2 = data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

  items <- df[i, 'secs']
  idd <- df[i, 'first']

  for (ss in 0:items) {  # run once for secs=0
    if (items == 0) { items <- 1 }

    df2[idd+ss, 'time'] <- idd+ss

    if (is.null(df2[idd+ss, 'tot']) || is.na(df2[idd+ss, 'tot'])) {
      df2[idd+ss, 'tot'] <- df[i, 'tot']
    } else {
      df2[idd+ss, 'tot'] <- df2[idd+ss, 'tot'] + df[i, 'tot']
    }

    if (is.null(df2[idd+ss, 'amount']) || is.na(df2[idd+ss, 'amount'])) {
      df2[idd+ss, 'amount'] <- df[i, 'amount']/items
    } else {
      df2[idd+ss, 'amount'] <- df2[idd+ss, 'amount'] + df[i, 'amount']/items
    }

    if (is.null(df2[idd+ss, 'size']) || is.na(df2[idd+ss, 'size'])) {
      df2[idd+ss, 'size'] <- df[i, 'size']/items
    } else {
      df2[idd+ss, 'size'] <- df2[idd+ss, 'size'] + df[i, 'size']/items
    }

  }
}
```

You can probably optimize this a lot and achieve good performance using only loops, but I bet that better algorithms exist. Maybe you could somehow [expand/duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894775/how-can-you-replicate-each-row-of-an-r-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-repl) the rows with `secs > 0`, while increasing the `first` (timestamp) values of the expanded rows and adjust `amount`, `size`, and `tot` metrics on the fly:

```
now original data..

  amount  size   tot first secs
1      4   164     1     1    0
2      4   164     1     1    1
3      3   124     1     1    2


magically becomes

  amount  size   tot first
1      4   164     1     1
2      2    82     1     1
3      2    82     1     2
4      1 41.33     1     1
5      1 41.33     1     2
6      1 41.33     1     3
```

After this pre-processing step aggregation would be trivial using [plyr  ddply](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plyr/docs/ddply), of course in efficient parallel mode.

All example ddply, apply etc. function examples I was able to find operate on per-row or per-column basis, making it hard to modify other rows. Hopefully I don't have to rely on awk-magic.

**Update:** The mentioned algorithm can easily exhaust your memory when the expansion is done "as is". Some kind of "on the fly" calculation is thus preferred, where we don't map everything to memory. Mattrition's answer is however correct and helped a lot, so marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: You need to explain in simple terms how you arrive from the input to the output shown in the question.

Comment: Your current implementation also has a few syntax and other errors. As it is, it doesn't produce any output. I can't even see how it would produce your suggested output, since you never assign anything to a column called "time".

Comment: True. Added a brief explanation and a 'time' assignment.

Comment: Still won't work. Try testing the code yourself please.

Comment: The original for-loop was redacted to present the functionality. Added the whole code in all its beauty. You can throw away the 'time' altogether if we use row.names(df2) = "1" "2" "3" "4" as the time.

Comment: Why do you average only the first `amount` and `size` (3.5, 144) and not the rest? 34.5 is 3.5 + 31 where 31 is the sum of all amounts in first=2, isn't it? Also, how do you arrive at `3,8` and `4,2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an implementation using `data.table`. I chose `data.table` for its aggregation abilities, but it's a nifty and efficient class to work with too.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)

# Using the "expand" solution linked in the Q. 
# +1 to secs to allow room for 0-values
dtr <- dt[rep(seq.int(1, nrow(dt)), secs+1)] 

# Create a new seci column that enumerates sec for each row of dt
dtr[,seci := dt[,seq(0,secs),by=1:nrow(dt)][,V1]]

# All secs that equal 0 are changed to 1 for later division
dtr[secs==0, secs := 1]

# Create time (first+seci) and adjusted amount and size columns
dtr[,c("time", "amount2", "size2") := list(first+seci, amount/secs, size/secs)]

# Aggregate selected columns (tot, amount2, and size2) by time
dtr.a <- dtr[,list(tot=sum(tot), amount=sum(amount2), size=sum(size2)), by=time]


dtr.a
   time tot amount  size
1:    1   2    3.5   144
2:    2   6   34.5 16327
3:    3   8   36.5 16773
4:    4   2    2.0   232
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's a good intro to data.table basics!


Unfortunately in my case the first line `dtr <- dt[rep(seq.int(1, nrow(dt)), secs+1)] ` is too resource intensive with the whole dataset of around 100 000 000 rows, so I run out of memory: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.8 Gb`. I'll try to split this set to smaller chunks later on.

Comment: Sounds like you need something a little complicated than generating the full-sized data set first...

Comment: Yup. I solved the situation by using a server with more RAM. You could easily write a loop to save the expanded values to e.g. separate files and then aggregate the statistics from there.

Comment: @ylijumala glad you could solve it with the old brute-force "more memory" approach!