# Replicate rows in a R data frame and index new duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe

How to replicate rows in a R dataframe based on a condition is explained here:

[Replicate each row of data.frame and specify the number of replications for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894775/how-can-you-replicate-each-row-of-an-r-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-repl)

But I also want to index new duplicates, in a new column. I.e the first duplicate would be indexed 1, the second 2, the third 3...

Considering the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(var1=c('a', 'b', 'c'), var2=c('d', 'e', 'f'), freq=1:3)

>df
  var1 var2 freq
1    a    d    1
2    b    e    2
3    c    f    3
```

I can duplicate each row based on the column freq this way:

```
df.expanded <- df[rep(row.names(df), df$freq),]

>df.expanded
  var1 var2 freq
1    a    d    1
2    b    e    2
3    b    e    2
4    c    f    3
5    c    f    3
6    c    f    3
```

What I want is having also an index to differentiate these new duplicates, like this:

```
>df.expanded
  var1 var2 freq  ind
1    a    d    1    1
2    b    e    2    1
3    b    e    2    2
4    c    f    3    1
5    c    f    3    2
6    c    f    3    3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.expanded$ind <- unlist(sapply(df$freq, seq_len))
```

Comment: +1. Also (for completeness), you could use ``data.table``.
``df.expanded[,ind:=seq(1,.N),by="var1"]``

Answer (score 1):

```
df.expanded$ind <- sequence(df$freq)
#    var1 var2 freq ind
#1      a    d    1   1
#2      b    e    2   1
#2.1    b    e    2   2
#3      c    f    3   1
#3.1    c    f    3   2
#3.2    c    f    3   3
```