# Strange error when expanding data.table

Tags: r, data.table

[We stumbled upon some strange behaviour trying to expand a data.table.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31243298/468305) The following code works alright:

```
dt <- data.table(var1=1:2e3, var2=1:2e3, freq=1:2e3)
system.time(dt.expanded <- dt[ ,list(freq=rep(1,freq)),by=c("var1","var2")])
##    user  system elapsed 
##    0.05    0.01    0.06
```

But using the following `data.table`

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(var1=sample(letters,1000,replace=T),var2=sample(LETTERS,1000,replace=T),freq=sample(1:10,1000,replace=T))
```

with the same code gives

```
Error in rep(1, freq) : invalid 'times' argument
```

**My question**
Might this be a bug in `data.table`?

(I got the syntax of the this example from [R Machine Learning Essentials](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/r-machine-learning-essentials))

**Edit**
So the problem really seems to be with `rep` and not with `data.table`. The help page for `rep` says for the parameter `times`:

> A integer vector giving the (non-negative) number of times to repeat each element if of length length(x), or to repeat the whole vector if of length 1.

The second `data.table` creates `times` of different length than `x` which throws the error.

Comment: I have no error. What versions of R and R Studio are you using.

Comment: @MikeWise: R version 3.1.1, RStudio Version 0.99.441 - could this be it?

Comment: I am using R version 3.1.3, RStudio Version 0.99.447.

Comment: Also my data.table was built with version 3.1.2

Comment: @MikeWise: My data.table was built with version 3.1.3

Comment: Yeah, I see the same error with data.table 1.9.4, R 3.2.0

Comment: I just upgraded R to version 3.2.1 and reinstalled data.table: still the same error!

Comment: What I find weird is that removing the redundant `by` clause makes the first one break, too. I mean `dt[ ,.(rep(1,freq))]`

Comment: Wierd that I had no error

Comment: @MikeWise Are you sure you ran the code as described (make `dt` according to the second bit; and then re-run the `system.time` thing)? I suspect that `rep` has always worked this way.

Comment: I'm getting the error on R3.2.1, data.table 1.9.4

Comment: if you replace `letters` and `LETTERS` with `1:2e3` it seems to behave as expected... but if you replace them with `1:26` it still breaks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess: when `rep(x,times)` is given a vector for `times`, it insists that `x` be the same length (instead of doing the natural thing in R and recycling). So manual recycling works:

```
dt[ ,.(rep(rep(1,.N),freq)), by=.(var1,var2)]
```

Seems to be a problem in base R (or maybe it's deliberate?), not in `data.table`. The OP didn't hit this problem in the first example because `by=.(var1,var2)` ensured that only one row was returned for each group, so the `times` argument was a scalar.

Comment: So what has the `by` clause to do with it?

Comment: @vonjd The `by` clause ensured that `times` was a scalar, not a vector. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Technically there are no scalars in R, only vectors with length 1... still not understanding the problem fully :-(

Comment: I'm using "scalar" as a shorthand for a vector of length 1, yes.

Comment: @vonjd Try `dt[,.N,by=.(var1,var2)][,table(N)]` to see the different group sizes in `dt`. If any of them are different from `1`, the error will be thrown.