# Create vector with number of each type of item determined by another vector

Tags: r, vector

In R, suppose I have a vector of 365 non-negative integers.  From this, I want to generate a vector of dates between 2015/1/1 and 2015/12/31.  A day will be listed `k` times in the new vector where `k` is the corresponding number in the first vector.  That is `k` is element `i` of the first vector where the date is the `i`th day of the year.

For example, if the first vector is

```
c(1, 0, 2, ..., 2)
```

then the second vector should be

```
c(2015/1/1, 2015/1/3, 2015/1/3, ..., 2015/12/31, 2015/12/31)
```

Is there a way to create this second vector as a whole, rather than row by row?  (I can certainly figure out how to do it row-by-row.)

Comment: And for repeating rows of a data frame: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2894775/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `rep` function as well as `seq.Date` to do this:

**Create Data**

```
set.seed(123) 
kvec <- sample(0:10, 365, replace = T) #create the nonnegative integers
#create sequence of dates
date_vec <- seq.Date(from = as.Date('2015-01-01'), to = as.Date('2015-12-31'), by = 'day')
```

**Use `rep()`**

```
#let rep() do the work
k_date_vec <- rep(date_vec, times = kvec)
```

**Result**

```
head(kvec)
[1]  3  8  4  9 10  0
head(k_date_vec)
[1] "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-02" "2015-01-02" "2015-01-02"
```