# Expand Row with Multiple Observations into Individual Rows

Tags: r

Just wondering if there is a way to expand rows which have multiple observations, into rows of unique observations using R? I have data in an excel spreadsheet with the variable headings: Lease, Line, Bay, Date, Predators, Food.Index, DD, MM, YY.

On some dates, there have been multiple predators (from 1 to 4) recorded in the same row. Other days just have 0. On a day where there has been 4 predators recorded, I would like to somehow transform the data to show four unique observations (instead of one row with 4 recorded under "Predators").

I have 1669 rows of data and multiple rows need to be expanded

Example of Data set 
[image]
Many thanks for your help in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f31sz.png)

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to convert your data from wide to long format. Maybe search on those terms, and check out `gather` in `tidyr` for one way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have come across these functions in my search to solve the problem I have, however these options don't appear to do exactly what I require.

Comment: If you're after an exact solution, post a reproducible example that includes representative data and shows what the output you want would look like.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replicate each row of data.frame and specify the number of replications for each row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894775/replicate-each-row-of-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications-for-each)

Comment: In the example dataset attached, row 4, which shows a 2 under predators, I would like to transform this into two rows, each showing 1 predator in each row. Then I would like to apply this to the entire dataset, so each row can only have a maximum of 1 predator. I have 1669 rows of data, so it will be difficult to specify the number of replications for each row, without going through each row and having a really long code.

Comment: images != data, please add a minimal example of your data problem,`data <- read.table(text = "some data")` and check the guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `df[rep(1:nrow(df), df$Predators), ]`

Comment: Thank you Axeman. This code also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your data in a data.frame, `df`, one possible solution would be

```
df.expanded <- df[rep(row.names(df), df$Predators), ]
```

EDIT: If you also want to keep the rows with 0 predators, you can use `pmax` to always return at least one:

```
df.expanded <- df[rep(row.names(df), pmax(df$Predators, 1)),]
```

Here the `pmax(df$Predators, 1)` will return the elementwise maximum of `df$Predators` and `1` so that it returns a new vector where each element is at least 1 but takes the value of `df$Predators` if that number is greater than 1.

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much. This works! Additional rows are recorded which represent each observation. If there were 4 predators, each row shows '4', however I can reassign these to have a value of 1. Many thanks for your help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Just one query, this gets rid of all observations that have a 0 value recorded. I would still like these observations - is there a way to keep these?

Comment: I have updated the answer to account for that scenario.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much. You are amazing :)