# How to expand dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this kind of data:

```
df <- data.frame(year=c(1999,1999,1999,2000,2000,2001,2011,2011,2011,2011), class=c("A","B","C","A","C","A","B","C","D","E"), 
             n=c(10,20,30,12,15,40,50,55,60,5), occurs=c(0,1,3,4,2,0,0,11,12,2))



> df
   year class  n occurs
1  1999     A 10      0
2  1999     B 20      1
3  1999     C 30      3
4  2000     A 12      4
5  2000     C 15      2
6  2001     A 40      0
7  2011     B 50      0
8  2011     C 55     11
9  2011     D 60     12
10 2011     E  5      2
```

I would like to expand this data like this:

```
   year class  n occurs
1  1999     A  1      0
1  1999     A  2      0
1  1999     A  3      0
...
1  1999     A 10      0

2  1999     B  0     0
2  1999     B  1     0
2  1999     B  2     0
...  
2  1999     B 20     1
3  1999     C  1     1
3  1999     C  1     1
3  1999     C  1     0
3  1999     C  1     0
.. the rest of occurs is seq of zeros...because `n-occurs` = 27 zeros and seq of 3x `1`.
```

I want to expand the rows `n` times as indicated by column `n` and so that the `occurs` column expands to flag `0` or `1` n-times according to the number of `occurs` columns number so if column `occurs` has interger `5` and column `n = 10` then there will be `n` rows (year and class the same) and flags `occurs` `5 times zero` and `5 times number one`.

**EDIT:** Please note the new sequence of `occurs` (seq only of `0` and `1`) is based on `n-occurs` for number of `0`s and number of `1` is determined by number `occurs`.

Comment: `do.call(expand.grid, df)`

Comment: much faster in my experience is `do.call(data.tabe::CJ, df)`; `CJ` also has a `unique` argument, which it looks like you may want

Comment: The column `occurs` should have only 0, 1 values ..

Comment: Here, you'd basically do `df[rep(1:nrow(df), df$n),]`.

Comment: Very close to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894775/replicate-each-row-of-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications-for-each

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the final element of n and also you don't explain where you want the 0s and 1s of occurs. For example, should all 1s be at the end? or a random placement of 1s?

Comment: You should clarify by posting a complete example (with corresponding desired output). I think I get it, but it's still unnecessarily opaque.

Comment: @Frank: Thanks for looking into this. I'm underestimating ....I keep thinking the example is sufficient.... I expanded now, I hope this time is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `do.call` and `lapply` calls using the `data.frame()` constructor with build of *occurs*:

```
df_List <- lapply(seq(nrow(df)), FUN=function(d){
    occ <- c(rep(1, df$occurs[[d]]), rep(0, df$n[[d]]-df$occurs[[d]]))

    data.frame(year=df$year[[d]], class=df$class[[d]], n=seq(df$n[[d]]), occurs=occ)
})

finaldf <- do.call(rbind, df_List)
head(finaldf, 20)
#    year class  n occurs
# 1  1999     A  1      0
# 2  1999     A  2      0
# 3  1999     A  3      0
# 4  1999     A  4      0
# 5  1999     A  5      0
# 6  1999     A  6      0
# 7  1999     A  7      0
# 8  1999     A  8      0
# 9  1999     A  9      0
# 10 1999     A 10      0
# 11 1999     B  1      1
# 12 1999     B  2      0
# 13 1999     B  3      0
# 14 1999     B  4      0
# 15 1999     B  5      0
# 16 1999     B  6      0
# 17 1999     B  7      0
# 18 1999     B  8      0
# 19 1999     B  9      0
# 20 1999     B 10      0
```

Comment: This solution would work, but the `occurs` column should give only either `0` or `1` values. You have also `occurs=3` there. To sample number of `0s` and `1's is based on the `n` and `occurs` so number of `1` is determined by `occurs` and number of `0` is determined by `n-occurs`.

Comment: @Maximilian - see my answer to address this.

Comment: I'm exactly testing that but see the last row E with 5 n and 22 occurs. This leaves us a negative.

Comment: You are abosolutely right! Sorry about that, I'm correcting that!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R method that is closely related to the linked post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894775/replicate-each-row-of-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications-for-each) and in my comment above. The answer is provides the method for generating the first two columns of the data.frame.

```
dat <- data.frame(df[1:2][rep(1:nrow(df), df$n),],
                  n=sequence(df$n),
                  occurs=unlist(mapply(function(x, y) rep(0:1, c(x-y, y)), df$n, df$occurs)))
```

Here, the first 2 columns are generated using that answer. n is generated using sequence, and occurs uses `mapply` and `rep`, returning a vector with `unlist`. This puts the 1s at the end. You could use `1:0` to put the 1s at the beginning or feed the resulting vector to `sample` within `mapply` to get a random ordering of 1s and 0s.

We can check that the data.frame has the proper number of rows:

```
nrow(dat) == sum(df$n)
[1] TRUE
```

The first 15 observations of

```
head(dat, 15)
    year class  n occurs
1   1999     A  1      0
1.1 1999     A  2      0
1.2 1999     A  3      0
1.3 1999     A  4      0
1.4 1999     A  5      0
1.5 1999     A  6      0
1.6 1999     A  7      0
1.7 1999     A  8      0
1.8 1999     A  9      0
1.9 1999     A 10      0
2   1999     B  1      0
2.1 1999     B  2      0
2.2 1999     B  3      0
2.3 1999     B  4      0
2.4 1999     B  5      0
```