# if (freq) x$counts else x$density length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: histogram

for my thesis I have to calculate the number of workers at risk of substitution by machines. I have calculated the probability of substitution (X) and the number of employee at risk (Y) for each occupation category. I have a dataset like this:

```
         X         Y

1      0.1300      0
2      0.1000      0
3      0.0841     1513
4      0.0221     287
5      0.1175     3641
....
700    0.9875     4000
```

I tried to plot a histogram with this command:

```
hist(dataset1$X,dataset1$Y,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,30000),breaks=100,main="Distribution",xlab="Probability",ylab="Number of employee")
```

But I get this error:

```
In if (freq) x$counts else x$density
length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Can someone tell me what is the problem and write me the right command?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is worth pointing out that the message displayed is a Warning message, and should not prevent the results being plotted. However, it does indicate there are some issues with the data.

Without the full dataset, it is not 100% obvious what may be the problem. I believe it is caused by the data not being in the correct format, with two potential issues. Firstly, some values have a value of 0, and these won't be plotted on the histogram. Secondly, the observations appear to be inconsistently spaced.

Histograms are best built from one of two datasets:

1. A dataframe which has been aggregated grouped into consistently sized bins.
2. A list of values X which in the data

I prefer the second technique. As originally shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894775/replicate-each-row-of-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications-for-each) The `expandRows()` function in the package `splitstackshape` can be used to repeat the number of rows in the dataframe by the number of observations:

```
set.seed(123)
dataset1 <- data.frame(X = runif(900, 0, 1), Y = runif(900, 0, 1000))

library(splitstackshape)
dataset2 <- expandRows(dataset1, "Y")

hist(dataset2$X, xlim=c(0,1))
dataset1$bins <- cut(dataset1$X, breaks = seq(0,1,0.01), labels = FALSE)
```

[image]