# expand several columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

My `dataframe` looks like:

```
        date     nights       rooms  searches
1 2018-01-01          2           1        30
2 2018-01-01          2           2         1
3 2018-01-01          3           1       115
```

I need to **expand date, rooms and searches columns by nights column**. Rooms and searches do not change expanding by nights. Expanding date column by nights affects date column as follows:

```
         date     rooms  searches
 1 2018-01-01         1        30
 2 2018-01-02         1        30
 4 2018-01-01         2         1
 5 2018-01-02         2         1
 7 2018-01-01         1       115
 8 2018-01-02         1       115
 9 2018-01-03         1       115
```

Comment: Do you want the number of repetitions to be `nights` or `nights+1`

Comment: nights. I have just edited it.

Comment: @LAP not the same. Those post expand data columns without rules.

Comment: See solutions posted here: [Replicate each row of data.frame...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2894775/4408538) E.g. `df[rep(row.names(df), df$nights), ]`

Comment: Thanks @JosephWood. 
I'm more comfortable with dplyr&tidyverse libraries.

Comment: I was thinking it would be really nice if there was a `dplyr` solution in the linked answer.

Comment: @Sotos This question needs to create a column containing a sequence of dates, so I think it is not an exact duplicate of the question you referred to.

Comment: @www IMO It should be enough but I reopened just in case the reference does not go with the Q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(date = map2(date, nights, ~seq(.x, .x + nights - 1, by = "day"))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(date, rooms, searches)

dt2
# # A tibble: 7 x 3
#         date rooms searches
#       <date> <int>    <int>
# 1 2018-01-01     1       30
# 2 2018-01-02     1       30
# 3 2018-01-01     2        1
# 4 2018-01-02     2        1
# 5 2018-01-01     1      115
# 6 2018-01-02     1      115
# 7 2018-01-03     1      115
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "        date     nights       rooms  searches
1 2018-01-01          2           1        30
                 2 2018-01-01          2           2         1
                 3 2018-01-01          3           1       115",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I updated my answer to remove the use of the `lubridate` package because functions from this package are not strictly required.