# How to duplicate rows 1 - 50 in R?

Tags: r, duplicates, rows

I am sure this is super simple, but I just can't find it..

How would you duplicate the first 10, 20 or 50 rows for all variables in a dataset and just add them as new rows?

Comment: `rbind(df, df[1:10, ])`

Comment: This question provides useful insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894775/replicate-each-row-of-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications-for-each

Answer (score 1):

R's subsetting allows you to assign objects to indexes that don't exist, so you can just set new rows to contain the original rows:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)
df[11:20, ] <- df[1:10, ]
df
#>     x  y
#> 1   1 11
#> 2   2 12
#> 3   3 13
#> 4   4 14
#> 5   5 15
#> 6   6 16
#> 7   7 17
#> 8   8 18
#> 9   9 19
#> 10 10 20
#> 11  1 11
#> 12  2 12
#> 13  3 13
#> 14  4 14
#> 15  5 15
#> 16  6 16
#> 17  7 17
#> 18  8 18
#> 19  9 19
#> 20 10 20
```

Created on 2018-05-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
z <- rbind( mtcars , mtcars[ 1:10, ] )

nrow( mtcars)
nrow( z )
```