# Melt or Replicate rows in a data table a certain number of times and include counter in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, reshape2

I would like to "expand" a dataframe, duplicating the information on some columns the number of times indicated by a fifth column.

What would the most efficiency to achieve this task with R? (Open to Data Table or Dplyer, reshape solutions).

#### Original Dataframe/DataTable:

```
   f_1 f_2        d_1        d_2 i_1
1:   1   A 2016-01-01       <NA>  NA
2:   2   A 2016-01-02       <NA>  NA
3:   2   B 2016-01-03 2016-01-01   2
4:   3   C 2016-01-04       <NA>  NA
5:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   5
```

#### Desired Dataframe/DataTable

```
    f_1 f_2        d_1        d_2 i_1
 1:   1   A 2016-01-01       <NA>  NA
 2:   2   A 2016-01-02       <NA>  NA
 3:   2   B 2016-01-03 2016-01-01   1
 4:   2   B 2016-01-03 2016-01-01   2
 5:   3   C 2016-01-04       <NA>  NA
 6:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   1
 7:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   2
 8:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   3
 9:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   4
10:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   5
```

#### Reproducible data:

```
DT <- data.table(
  f_1 = factor(c(1,2,2,3,4)),
  f_2 = factor(c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D")),
  d_1 = as.Date(c("2016-01-01","2016-01-02","2016-01-03","2016-01-04","2016-01-05")),
  d_2 = as.Date(c(NA,NA,"2016-01-01",NA,"2016-01-02")),
  i_1 = as.integer(c(NA,NA,2,NA,5)))
```

Thanks and sorry if it is duplicated. I am struggling with this kind of reshaping exercises.

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894775

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution. Basically, group by those columns that you want to duplicate and generate sequence of integers using the number in `i_1`

```
DT[, .(i_1=if(!is.na(i_1)) seq_len(i_1) else i_1), 
    by=c(names(DT)[-ncol(DT)])]
```

output:

```
    f_1 f_2        d_1        d_2 i_1
 1:   1   A 2016-01-01       <NA>  NA
 2:   2   A 2016-01-02       <NA>  NA
 3:   2   B 2016-01-03 2016-01-01   1
 4:   2   B 2016-01-03 2016-01-01   2
 5:   3   C 2016-01-04       <NA>  NA
 6:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   1
 7:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   2
 8:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   3
 9:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   4
10:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   5
```

Or another way using `data.table`. For each row, create a sequence of numbers using `i_1` and add the original data to that sequence with `c(.SD[, -"i_1], .....` and finally remove the `by` column

```
DT[, c(.SD[, -"i_1"], .(i_1=if (!is.na(i_1)) seq_len(i_1) else i_1)), 
    by=seq_len(DT[,.N])][,-1L]
```

Comment: Used the first line and worked perfectly. Thanks for the concise answer.

Answer (score 3):

Are you OK replacing `i_1` with `1` when it's `NA`? If so, the following would be slightly more readable:

First, repeat the rows the specified number of times (*ad hoc* accounting for the missing values of `i_1`, using `replace` courtesy of @Frank):

```
DT_out = DT[rep(1:.N, replace(i_1, is.na(i_1), 1L))]
```

This could be just `DT[rep(1:.N, i_1)]` if we've already replaced `DT[is.na(i_1), i_1 := 1L]`.

All that's left is to update the values of `i_1`. There are simpler versions of this, depending on your data's particulars. Here I think is the more general version:

```
DT_out[!is.na(i_1), i_1 := rowidv(.SD), .SDcols = !'i_1'][]
#     f_1 f_2        d_1        d_2 i_1
#  1:   1   A 2016-01-01       <NA>  NA
#  2:   2   A 2016-01-02       <NA>  NA
#  3:   2   B 2016-01-03 2016-01-01   1
#  4:   2   B 2016-01-03 2016-01-01   2
#  5:   3   C 2016-01-04       <NA>  NA
#  6:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   1
#  7:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   2
#  8:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   3
#  9:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   4
# 10:   4   D 2016-01-05 2016-01-02   5
```

`rowid` and `rowidv` give the row number within the groups defined by the variables it's passed. You can compare with `rowid(f_2)`, `rowid(f_1)`, and `rowid(f_1, f_2)` to get an idea of what I mean. `rowidv(.SD)` is a shorthand for `rowid(f_1, f_2, d_1, d_2)`, since we exclude `i_1` from the columns in `.SD`.