# replicate the row depending on a column

Tags: r

I have a data set looking at 22.000 individuals. However there is a time variable to it telling me when this individual was observed the first time and when the last time. So I produced an additional column that tells me the absolute number of quarters that the individual was observed. Now I want to make this dataset a panel data set and replicate each individual by the number of quarter it has been observed.
I found this question

[Replicate each row of data.frame and specify the number of replications for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894775/replicate-each-row-of-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications-for-each)

which matches my concern very well. but punching in the code:

```
df.expanded <- df[rep(seq(nrow(df)), df$Quartale), 1:2]
```

"Quartale" is name of the Var for quarters
produces this error: 
Error in df$Quatarle : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For code debugging please always ask with a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451) example per the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [`r`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) tag description, with the desired output. You can use `dput()`, `reprex::reprex()` or built-in data sets for reproducible data.

Comment: Can you share what your dataframe looks like? And tell us the type of `df$Quartale` using `typeof()`

Comment: Based on that error message, it also looks like you might have a typo.  Is it `df$Quartale` or `df$Quatarle`

Comment: Sorry, for not getting back earlier...So I went back into the data and made several summary stats and in the end decided that the additional observation come with only very little variation, so I would artificially increase dataset. Hence, I did not follow up on this. again sorry for the late reply and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is more difficult to assess this without an example dataset, but I think you can use the `tidyr` package for this.

Assuming your data `df`, and your frequency count is `df$Quartale`, then the following should work:

```
library(tidyr)
uncount(df, Quartale)
```