# Repeat rows in data.table according to value of column

Tags: r, data.table, rep

I have a data table `dt` with 3 columns like this:

```
   coord_e coord_n proj_apartments
1: 2670789 1252252             120
2: 2670861 1252186              45
3: 2671109 1233883              34
4: 2671128 1244620              11
5: 2671134 1242050              39
6: 2671314 1241298              20
```

I want to repeat each row as many times as the number in the `proj_apartments`column – meaning the first row should be repeated 120 times, the second 45 and so long.

I think I need the `rep()` function, but I am struggling:

```
dt <- as.data.table(read.table(text = 
"coord_e coord_n proj_apartments
2670789 1252252             120
2670861 1252186              45
2671109 1233883              34
2671128 1244620              11
2671134 1242050              39
2671314 1241298              20", header=TRUE))

rep(dt[,c(coord_e,coord_n,proj_apartments)], times = dt[,proj_apartments])
```

The times argument is invalid in this way...

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: `tidyr::uncount(dt, proj_apartments)`

Comment: @RonakShah you should add that to your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56929313/5635580)

Comment: @Sotos I think it's already present there https://stackoverflow.com/a/48571794/3962914

Comment: @RonakShah Oh, did not notice it...and to think I looked to make sure lol