# From count to cases in R

Tags: r, data-structures, count, data.table, multiple-occurrence

I have a dataset with a column which indicate the number of occurence of a group constituted by multiples variables. Here `SEX`and `COLOR`.

```
CASES <- base::data.frame(SEX   = c("M", "M", "F", "F", "F"), 
                          COLOR = c("brown", "blue", "brown", "brown", "brown"))
COUNT <- base::as.data.frame(base::table(CASES))
COUNT
```

I need to change the structure of the dataset, so I have one row for each occurence of the group. Someone helped me to create a function which works perfectly.

```
countsToCases <- function(x, countcol = "Freq") {
    # Get the row indices to pull from x
    idx <- rep.int(seq_len(nrow(x)), x[[countcol]])
    # Drop count column
    x[[countcol]] <- NULL
    # Get the rows from x
    x[idx, ]
}

CASES <- countsToCases(base::as.data.frame(COUNT))
CASES
```

The problem is now that I have a HUGE dataset (the `babyname` dataset from tidytuesday), and this is not working since it's too slow.

```
db_babynames <- data.table::as.data.table(tuesdata$babyname)

db_babynames <- db_babynames[
  j = characters_n := stringr::str_count(string  = name,
                                         pattern = ".")
][
  j = c("year", "characters_n", "n")
]
```

I'm looking for a faster solution, working with the `data.table` package if possible.

Comment: Do you really need the uncounted version? Remember that you can do weighted summaries and plots.

Comment: I think so. I would like to create a `geom_point()` from this.

Comment: You will have a bunch of overlapped points. You can used the count to set the opacity and thats it.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the CASES at the beginning and CASES which is the output of the countsToCases function. Just the order?

Comment: @maydin No difference. It's just a code I use in other cheatsheet that I duplicated without thinking.

Comment: @JohanRosa No because I will use `position = ggplot2::position_jitter()` to handle the overlapped point. But I will give a try

Comment: Consider `tidyr::uncount()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an uncounted version is needed I would use `tidyr::uncount()`, but consider the recommendation in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60106338/10266675) to work with your original data

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

CASES <- base::data.frame(
  SEX   = c("M", "M", "F", "F", "F"),
  COLOR = c("brown", "blue", "brown", "brown", "brown")
  )

COUNT <- count(CASES, SEX, COLOR, name = 'Freq')

tidyr::uncount(base::as.data.frame(COUNT), Freq)
#>   SEX COLOR
#> 1   F brown
#> 2   F brown
#> 3   F brown
#> 4   M  blue
#> 5   M brown
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: So simple yet amazing. Thank you very much. I would love a `data.table` equivalent because I'm more used to but not sure there is one.

Comment: I added a post with a recommendation for someone with a problem like yours. There you will see how to do  weighted summary and plots.