# Duplicate a row whilst keeping rows that do not need duplicating?

Tags: r, duplicates, tidyverse, expand, rbind

I'm trying to duplicate a row within a dataset and also retain rows that do not need duplicating.

**Here is sample data:**

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(id = c('2292','2293','2294'), var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
                   freq = c(1, NA, NA))
```

**Before:**

```
    id var1 freq
1 2292    a    1
2 2293    b    0
3 2294    c    0
```

**After:**

```
      id var1 freq
1   2292    a    1
2 2292.1    a    1
3   2293    b    0
4   2294    c    0
```

**I have looked at the following questions:**

[Repeat each row of data.frame the number of times specified in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894775/repeat-each-row-of-data-frame-the-number-of-times-specified-in-a-column)

**However when following examples:**

```
df %>% uncount(freq, .remove = FALSE)
```

**I get:**

```
    id var1 freq
1 2292    a    1
```

It would be very helpful to select by `id` and then duplicate selected `id`'s whilst retaining rows that do not need to be duplicated and that I wish to keep.

**I have also tried:**

```
df %>% map_df(., rep, .$freq)
```

**This comes close:**

```
df %>% 
    filter(row_number() %in% c(1)) %>% 
    rbind.fill(df) %>%
    arrange(id)
```

**Result:**

```
    id var1 freq
1 2292    a    1
2 2292    a    1
3 2293    b    0
4 2294    c    0
```

But ideally I'd like to select rows by `id` instead of `row_number` and then update the `id` so that it becomes `2992.1`. I can delete the `freq` column after. I am using `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not filter these out first and then join.  A suggested approach

```
#store id to duplicate in a vector

ids_v <- c(2292)

#Now filter out these and join

df %>% filter(id %in% ids_v) %>%
  mutate(id = paste0(id, '.1')) %>%
  rbind(df) %>% arrange(id)

      id var1 freq
1   2292    a    1
2 2292.1    a    1
3   2293    b   NA
4   2294    c   NA
```

I hope this should serve the purpose